# Output stream writing more that read - C#

Tags: c#, .net, stream, filestream

I am having a brain-dead moment, staring blankly at this little section of code for 10 mins now... can someone please tell me why the output file (test2.txt) contains more text that the file it is reading from (test.txt) ??

Here is teh code:

```
FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test.txt", FileMode.Open);
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test2.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\test.txt").Length + "\n");

while (inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
{
      Console.WriteLine("bufferlength " + buffer.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray().Length);
      Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\test2.txt").Length);
      outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      outputStream.Flush();
      Console.ReadKey();
}

Console.WriteLine("\n" + inputStream.Length);
Console.WriteLine(outputStream.Length);
Console.Read();
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Rohit Vats has the answer you could use. Keep in mind that when this is a large file, the constant writing to the `Console` can make it take a long time. Also I would increase the buffer size for less loss due to overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This is because you have created a byte array of size 1024. So, even in case inputStream length is less than 1024, it will still write 1024 bytes to your file.</strike>

You should initialize it with inputStream size so that only limited bytes gets written to your file:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.Length];
```

**UPDATE**

Silvermind in comment pointed out right, let buffer array size to be 1024. Instead `use byte size returned by Read` method to write to your file so that only bytes read gets written to file:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("bufferlength " + buffer.Where(x => x != 0)
                                                  .ToArray().Length);
    Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(@"D:\Temp\test2.txt").Length);
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); <- HERE
    outputStream.Flush();
}
```

---

On a sidenote, you should `dispose FileStream's` after use to avoid any memory leaks. You can `wrap them in using block` which will dispose it automatically for you after use.

```
using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test.txt",
                                                 FileMode.Open))
{
    using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test2.txt",
                                                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.Length];
        Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\test.txt").Length + "\n");
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bufferlength " + buffer.Where(x => x != 0)
                                                  .ToArray().Length);
            Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo(@"D:\Temp\test2.txt").Length);
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); <- HERE
            outputStream.Flush();
         }
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + inputStream.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(outputStream.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome DawnFreeze. Please accept an answer if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Perhaps it's a large file? Now you are putting the entire file in memory. My guess is that `Read` returns an `int` how many bytes are read and that he can use that.

Comment: @Silvermind - Yeah you are right. Updated an answer.. Thanks.!!